Creating a call graph for page table functionaility with Linux?
I have been trying to understand page table functionality within Linux (very recent version 6) and I am having trouble.
I've identified functions like pgd_alloc(), pmd_alloc() and pte_alloc(), as well as pgd_free(), pmd_free() and pte_free()...
But what I am really looking for is a nice call graph that shows exactly what is happening when I open a process in userspace and the page table gets initiated for that process. As well as when it is deleted.
Any tips or help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Type "linux kernel performance analysis" into your browser's search bar; read man perf, and be prepared to handle lots of data.
